# Error While Moving Files in Browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern, move-to

A user is receiving this strange error while inside a Document Library and attempting to move a file (drag n drop or 'Move to')

> The property 'RetainEditorAndModifiedOnMove' does not exist on type
>   'SP.MoveCopyOptions'. Make sure to only use property names that are
>   definide by the type

Nothing online about this, any indications or ideas?

[image]

Comment: Same Issue-- Same Day- (Possible issue on Backend)
I copied the file locally and then back up to directory. FYI Deleting and Restoring the Original did not change it properties when recovered from Recycle Bin

Comment: I have the same issue, same day.

Comment: face same issue,

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this issue on my SharePoint Online environment. "Drag&Drop" and "Move to" could work well and no error shows.

Please check if this issue occurs on all libraries on all sites. If yes, I suggest you create a new service request on Admin Center->Support.